# Skipping line and regex in awk

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I'm working with awk and I need to skip lines that are blank or comments. I've been trying inside the loop to see if it match the regex for this and then using next

```
{if ($0 ~"/^($|#)/" ) {next;}}
```

but the if statement is never getting hit and I can't figure out why. (My input has blank lines and comments)

I need to add this line inside of an awkscript in the block, not a command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're inside a block of `awk` code that doesn't benefit from default print of matching patterns and you need to use an `if` test , here is the basis for a solution

```
$ echo "a
b
c

d
#
#e

f

" | awk '{if ($0 ~ /^(#|$)/ ) {next;} ;print}'
```

produces output of

```
a
b
c
d
f
```

If you want to skip blank lines that have spaces/tabs included, you can add

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /^(#|[ \t]*$)/ ) {next;} ;print}'
#-------------------^^^^^^
#                   means char-class of space and tab char
#                   * means zero or more of preceding
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`, a regular expression is marked by the beginning and ending slashes.  If you place it inside quotes, it ceases to be a regex and becomes a string.  Thus, replace:

```
{if ($0 ~"/^($|#)/" ) {next;}}
```

With:

```
{if ($0 ~ /^($|#)/ ) {next;}}
```

#### Example

Consider the input file:

```
$ cat input
one
#comment
two

three

four
```

Now observe the `awk` script:

```
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /^($|#)/ ) {next;}} 1' input
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one:

```
awk '! /^($|#)/' infile
```

It uses a default action of print for each line that doesn't begin with `#` or is a blank one.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^$|#/{next} {print $0}'
```

would do the job

or

more simply

```
awk '/^[^$#]/ '
```

what it does?

`/^[^$#]/` matches each line to the regex and if a match is found, the default action to print the entire record is done.

`^` anchors the regex at the begining of the line.

`[^$#]` negatates the character class. ensures that the start of line is not followed by

`$` => line is empty, negation skips the line
`#` => comment

eg

```
$ cat input 
hello
#world

this is a
test

$ awk '/^[^$#]/ ' input 
hello
this is a
test
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused about how that fits into the if statement. Can you provide more of an example?

Comment: you need not use any if statements here. will add an explanation to the answer

Comment: see the edited answer. hope it became more clear

Comment: I need to use it inside of a script. I keep getting an error that's   
'awk {if ($0 ~ /^(#|[ \t]*$)/ ) {next;} ;print}'
 ^ invalid char ''' in expression
or something similar.

Comment: @Sams: is that a typo, or did you mean `awk '{if ($0 ~ /^(#|[ \t]*$)/ ) {next;} ;print}'` ? (notice the position of the opening single-quote character). Good luck.